# Json Encoder Expecting Value error in Python

Tags: python, json, api, github

I have a big Json File 350mb and I want to extract items from it. The code that I use is:

```
with open("commitsJson3.json","r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


for elem in data['items']:
    for e in elem['commit']:
       if 'message' in e:
           print(elem['commit'][e])
```

And the error that I get is:

**json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2180 (char 2179)**

I went to the specific column and line but I didn't see any problem. I tried to validate my json by some online validators but it crashes because it is too big. I can show you some sample of it but it is too big I hope you understand it.

---

{"total_count": 3, "incomplete_results": "False", "items": c "site_admin": False}, "committer": {"login": "acosding", "id": 1539, "node_id": "ASJKDHASAD", "avatar_url": "https://gits-5.s.fe.se/avatars/u/1329?", "gravatar_id": "", "url": "https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden", "html_url": "https://gits-5.s.fe.se/acollden", "followers_url": "https://https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/followers", "following_url": "https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/following{/other_user}", "gists_url": "https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/gists{/gist_id}", "starred_url": "https://https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/starred{/owner}{/repo}", "subscriptions_url": "https://https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/subscriptions", "organizations_url": "https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/orgs", "repos_url": "https://https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/repos", "events_url": "https://https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/events{/privacy}", "received_events_url": "https://https://gits-5.s.fe.se/api/v3/users/acollden/received_events", "type": "User"

---

Any help would be grateful to understand if the Json file has the problem how to validate it while being such a big file etc.

Thank you.

Comment: If I take you json extract it only goes to column 1111, can you share the full json file please, or at least an extract that goes beyond ```line 1 column 2180 (char 2179)```

Comment: I can share it. Do you want me to send it to you in email or smthing? Its 350mb

Comment: @lee-pai-long Where do you want me to send it to you?

Comment: 350mb will not pass on most email provider, can you try and see if an extract up to the column indicated by the error can be less than 50mb and use [filebin](https://filebin.ca) ?

Comment: @lee-pai-long Here it is https://filebin.ca/4dlrj3G96n2d/Json4.txt

Comment: Is the sample you posted correct? As it seems a `,` is missing in `"items": c "site_admin": False`

Comment: @LanteDellarovere Ok so I think something might happend. Because the file originally had single quotes ( ' ) and then I converted to string to replace quotes to double (") But I might have scrwed it up?

Comment: Aside from the missing delimiter `,` I think the real problem is that `c`, which, I guess, should be `"c"`

Comment: @LanteDellarovere I will provide the same sample of the single quoted file. Because in that there is no 'c' so its weird. Sec...

Comment: @LanteDellarovere Here it is https://filebin.ca/4dlwtO4dCqHD/Json5.txt

Comment: I posted an answer, I can't look at the whole file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the sample you provided is not well formatted, if I try to
decode just the first part:

```
my_json = '{"total_count": 3, "incomplete_results": "False", "items": c "site_admin": False}'
```

and I try to parse it I get:

```
import json

json.loads(my_json, encoding='utf-8-sig')

>>> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 60 (char 59)
```

which is referred to that `c` missing quotes, then If I fix this:

```
my_json = '{"total_count": 3, "incomplete_results": "False", "items": "c" "site_admin": False}'
print(json.loads(my_json, encoding='utf-8-sig'))

>>> JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 64 (char 63)
```

which is referred to the missing `,` after `items` key. After fixing this:

```
my_json = '{"total_count": 3, "incomplete_results": "False", "items": "c", "site_admin": False}'
print(json.loads(my_json, encoding='utf-8-sig'))

>>> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 79 (char 78)
```

which is referred to the last `False`. This can be fixed either by using `false`, or `"False"`, depending on the type you want this to be treated. 
But given that your first False is treated as a string:

```
my_json = '{"total_count": 3, "incomplete_results": "False", "items": "c", "site_admin": "False"}'
print(json.loads(my_json, encoding='utf-8-sig'))

>>> {'items': 'c', 'total_count': 3, 'site_admin': 'False', 'incomplete_results': 'False'}
```

And finally it works

Comment: Bro my file is different the original one. With the single quotes. Should I try another method to make it double quoted. But I cant do it smh....

Comment: Then I think you should open another question as this one is solved and It becomes very hard to understand what's going on without a more detailed description of what the original file is, and how you modify it